# Syncing mobile app database records with server

Tags: ios, database, server, synchronization

I am working on a project which has both web and mobile versions. So to keep the server records synced with mobile I am checking the records greater than the last modified date of individual modules.

Everything worked perfectly except records with same timestamp.

Eg: If there are 20 records with same timestamp and during sync 10 got inserted to mobile database and rest didn't go through for some reason like crashing. When it checks again with server as the last updated date is same it wont pull the remaining 10 records.

Current Logic

1. Sending the local module and it highest last modified time to server
   to check for any updates.
2. API responds whether there are any changes to individual modules
3. App requests the changed records.
4. API sends backs the records ( records greater than the last modified date sent from app )

Please suggest a work around so that records are not missed.

Comment: I don't get it, why don't you just define your "pull" method to pull every records that have a date greater or equal to the last modified date ?

Comment: In that case what happens is whenever the app checks with server for any change there will be records always with the same last modified date.